# Why Compiler reset code differently for conditional statments?

Tags: java

Java compiler is smart enough to reset the source code when it generates the class file. Below is an example to understand this. I have created one java file Compiler.java compiler generates class file of this file as Compiler.class.

```
Compiler .java

public class Compiler {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = true;
    {// block1
        if (a) {
            System.out.println("I am in if");
        } else if (b) {
            System.out.println("I am in else if");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I am in else");
        }
    }
    {// block2
        if (a) {
        } else if (b) {
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
Compiler .class   

public class Compiler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a = false;
        boolean b = true;
        if (a) {
            System.out.println("I am in if");
        } else if (b) {
            System.out.println("I am in else if");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I am in else");
        }
        if (!a) {
        }
    }
}
```

If one can observe the diffence between block1 and block2 in generated class file. One can understand that how java compiler work in smart way. Compiler checks the first “if else if” conditional statments in block1 and finds there are something to execute within these statement(i.e print statements) so it generate block1 as smilar as in java source . In second block , I mean in block2 compiler finds there is nothing to execute within if -esle if statements so it converts and reset the block2 as you can see class file above. Compiler simply converts the “if else if block” to if statement which will be executed or not be executed depending on boolean value.

In second block if statement also contains negation. Could somebody explain this ? Thanks is advance.

Comment: This formatting gave me cancer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler's seeing there's some code in the first-level 'else' of the block2, and nothing in the matching if, thus reverting the condition to reducing the unnecessary 'if-else' to a simple 'if'.

It then moves on in depth on the second-level if-else, finds the code would do nothing no matter the variables state, thus removing the whole second-level if-else.

At this point, the now-alone first-level 'if' should contain the second-level block code, but that block just was entirely removed and the compiler didn't "come back" to check it again, thus leaving the first 'if' empty.